# Latency with Local fonts vs Google fonts for @font-face

Tags: font-face, latency, google-webfonts

I see a few questions surrounding this topic, but none of them answer this question specifically. I am working with a client on a high traffic web site (major fashion brand) and there is discussion about web fonts installed locally on our server, vs google web fonts loaded through their service.

While faced with the decision of using the free service offered by the GoogleApi and it's web fonts service, vs purchasing the distribution licenses needed for various protectd fonts (or subscribing to a service which covers this for us) the cost issue is know... Google wins because it is free.

*HOWEVER...* when faced with the bandwidth/latency issue of loading the fonts from our server vs using the google service I am not certain which would be a better option.

So... Is it true that the google service would have a higher latency as compared to a font served up from our server locally?

I'm sorry I do not have more information on the servers we have set up, but we have numerous servers set up to handle the bandwidth required to maintain the load we receive daily. As I said we are a global fashion retail company.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your first question seems impossible for anyone but you to answer, given it's a question about the latency of *your* server. Your second question isn't actually a question, and doesn't seem relevant to the latency theme established by the other paragraphs. Maybe you should post it as a separate question and actually *ask* whether fonts loaded with `@font-face` are really loaded when they're not used.

Comment: Assuming that your server as such doesn't have noticeable latency (due to being badly configured or being overloaded with requests), you can indeed expect your local files being served with less latency, since the client will reuse the existing TCP connection whereas in the other case it would have to do a DNS lookup on fonts.google.com and go through the connection handshake, which translates to 3-6 RTTs worth 10-50ms each overall. But note the word "assuming" at the start. WIthout knowing anything about your server, nothing and anything is possible.

Comment: And as with all CDN solutions, the real benefit is that the visitor might already have the font in their cache from previously visiting some other site that uses the same font. In that case the file doesn't need to be downloaded at all and latency is (practically) zero. In any case unless you use dozens of different fonts on the same page the difference between local and CDN files is most likely unnoticeable to the user.